# select only 1 rows on 1 field which have 2 rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i've problem when getting data from my database.

the problem is when i want to get only 1 rows from 1 fields.

example :

in table ms_file i have 2 fields (product_id, path)

1. ..../dir/bg.1
2. ..../dir/bg.2

with the same product_id.

if i using join to this table (ms_file) i got error when using group by

> list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column.... which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

because on this query we got different 2 rows with the same product_id

how to solve it?

```
select ms_product.*, ms_file.path, users.name as users_name, ms_subcategory.name as subcategory from ms_product 
        left join users ON users.id = ms_product.users_id
        left join ms_subcategory ON ms_subcategory.id = ms_product.subcategory_id
        left join ms_file ON ms_file.product_id = ms_product.product_id
        where ms_product.status = "A" group by ms_product.product_id order by ms_product.created_at desc LIMIT 4
```

if i don't input GROUP BY on this query above, i got no error. but this query will show 2 rows from ms_file

if i using GROUP BY on this query above, i got error.

Comment: Please, show your query or some code

Comment: i've been updated.

Comment: Can you show what the SQL looks like with the GROUP BY clause you've tried.

Comment: done, the question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I using group concat and explode via php to get first array.